# Dynamically build JSON object list from Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to end up with the below JSON from an HTML form.

```
{
    "Name":"Curtis",
    "Phone":"555-555-5555",
    "Replacements":
    [
        {
            "Company":"ABC Company",
            "Amount":100
        },
        {
            "Company":"123 Company",
            "Amount":200
        },
    ]
}
```

I'm struggling with the JavaScript in regards to building the array for the replacements.

```
var o = {};
o["Name"] = $("#Name").val();
o["Phone"] = $("#Phone").val();

//How do I append the dynamic list of replacements here?
//$("#Company1").val();
//$("#Amount1").val();
//$("#Company2").val();
//$("#Amount2").val();

$("#txtJSON").val(JSON.stringify(o));
```

Comment: You should take a look at this: [Convert form data to JS object with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/convert-form-data-to-js-object-with-jquery)

Comment: Have you check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/convert-form-data-to-javascript-object-with-jquery/39248551#39248551

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create Replacements property array and push objects in it:

```
var o = {};
o.Name. = $("#Name").val();
o.Phone = $("#Phone").val();

o.Replacements = [];

o.Replacements.push({
    Company: $("#Company1").val(),
    Amount:  $("#Amount1").val()
}, {
    Company: $("#Company2").val(),
    Amount:  $("#Amount2").val()
});

$("#txtJSON").val(JSON.stringify(o));
```